# How do I create an emoji font?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, svg

I've got some svg/ai files that I'd like to turn into an emoji font. Is there a way to do this? Every time I try to import into FontLab, it only imports as a black and white glyph.

Comment: Similar to [Create a custom font with multi colours](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74338/create-a-custom-font-with-multi-colours).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a custom font with multi colours](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74338/create-a-custom-font-with-multi-colours)

Answer (score 0):

### Create & add Emojis to a font

Here you go!
You can create your own ***custom emojis*** and add them to a font to use them as any *symbol*, not just an image. There are several tools and methods available to help you do this.

1. One way to create custom emojis is to *use a graphic design program* such as ***Adobe Illustrator or Photoshop*** to create vector graphics of your emojis. Once you have created your emoji designs, you can use a *font creation tool* such as **FontLab or Glyphs** to import your designs and create a custom font that includes your emojis.
2. Another option is to use an *online custom emoji maker* such as **Kapwing or Angel Emoji Maker**. These tools allow you to create custom emojis using their built-in design tools and libraries of stickers, shapes, GIFs, and other creative assets. Once you have created your custom emojis, you can download them as image files and then use a font creation tool to import them into a custom font.

***Note:*** It’s important to note that creating a custom font with emojis can be a complex process and may require some technical knowledge and experience with graphic design and font creation tools. If you’re new to this process, it may be helpful to start by reading some tutorials or guides on how to ***create custom fonts and how to add custom emojis to a font***

---

R.N. Svlikes

Answer (score -2):

With latest update to Photoshop CC, it gained ability of emoji and SVG font support.

> Emoji fonts are an example of OpenType SVG fonts. Using Emoji fonts, you can include various colorful and graphical characters, such as smileys, flags, street signs, animals, people, food, and landmarks in your documents. OpenType SVG emoji fonts, such as the EmojiOne font, let you create certain composite glyphs from one or more other glyphs. For example, you can create the flags of countries or change the skin color of certain glyphs depicting people and body parts such as hands and nose.

[image]

> Create flags of countries: The "letters” (A, B, C, D, and so on) in EmojiOne do not correspond to the corresponding keys on the keyboard. When you combine these characters in the Glyphs Panel to make up a country’s ISO code, the two characters form the flag of that country. For example, US gives the American flag, GB gives the British flag, AR gives the Argentine flag, and IN gives the Indian flag.

[image]
[image]

Detailed information: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/svg-fonts.html

Comment: I was about to edit it while you are writing this. Thanks!

Comment: The question is about *creating* emoji fonts; Photoshop can now *use* them, but not *create* them.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not sure that this is a proper answer. The question was related to *create a new font*, the answer seems related to *using a font* in Photoshop CC.

Comment: As it is, this does not answer this question. But it does answer two others! One is slightly narrower than the other (and could be closed as a duplicate), but this answers [Emoji typing support in Illustrator or Photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/41545/30216) , for the Photoshop half. So I suggest you copy this answer over there and delete this.